# Vowpal Wabbit feature extraction

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I'm confused about the way vw extracts features. Consider a text classification problem where I want to use character ngrams as features. In the simplest case that illustrates my question, the input string is "aa" and I use 1-gram features only. So, the example should consist of a single feature "a" that has a count of 2, as follows:

```
$ echo "1 |X a:2" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = 
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
1.000000   1.000000            1         1.0   1.0000   0.0000        1

finished run
number of examples per pass = 1
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 1
weighted label sum = 1
average loss = 1
best constant = 1
total feature number = 1
X^a:108118:0.196698
```

However, if I pass the character string "aa" to vw (introducing spaces between the characters), vw reports 2 features:

```
$ echo "1 |X a a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = 
num sources = 1
average    since         example     example  current  current  current
loss       last          counter      weight    label  predict features
1.000000   1.000000            1         1.0   1.0000   0.0000        2

finished run
number of examples per pass = 1
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 1
weighted label sum = 1
average loss = 1
best constant = 1
total feature number = 2
X^a:108118:0.375311
```

The actual model contains only a single feature (as I would expect), but its weight (0.375311) is different than in the first model (0.196698).

When training on real datasets with higher-order n-grams, substantial differences in average loss can be observed depending on which input format is used. I looked at the source code in parser.cc, and given more time I could probably figure out what's going on; but if someone could please explain the discrepancy between the two cases above (is it a bug?) and/or point me to the relevant portions of the source, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose total feature number value is just a counter of observed features. For example you'll get 10 for following command:

```
$ echo "1 |X a" | vw --noconstant --passes 10 --cache_file f -k
```

I also saw in vw code that divides feature's regressor value by feature weight before printing out. That could be seen from following:

```
$ echo "1 |X a:1" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.393395
$ echo "1 |X a:2" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.196698
$ echo "1 |X a:3" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.131132
$ echo "1 |X a:10" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.039344
```

I would suspect that features are exclusive and examples like "|X a" and "|X a a" shall give same result, but they're not:

```
$ echo "1 |X a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.393395
$ echo "1 |X a a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.375311
$ echo "1 |X a a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.366083
```

I don't really know why. There shall be a logic behind that. But it works as expected (by me) if you specify --sort_features

```
$ echo "1 |X a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.393395
echo "1 |X a a a a a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f --sort_features && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.393395
```

The interesting fact is that if you specify --sort_features vw uses only first occurrence of feature. Example:

```
$ echo "1 |X a a:10" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f --sort_features && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.393395
$ echo "1 |X a a:2" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f --sort_features && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.393395
$ echo "1 |X a:10 a" | vw --noconstant --invert_hash f --sort_features && grep '^X^' f
X^a:108118:0.039344
```

I hope with these observations you will be able to make vw work as you need. But I'm not sure if this is a bug or feature. Will forward to vw authors to comment.

Comment: I haven't used `--sort_features` before and I wouldn't have expected it to produce the behavior in your examples. The help entry says "turn this on to disregard order in which features have been defined. This will lead to smaller cache sizes". But why would the order in which features are defined matter in the first place? Maybe that's the key to my original question.

Comment: I have no clue. I have raised that question on official page https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/425

Comment: In case you're not tracking the discussion with the author - his reply: _it's essentially a computational issue. We could try to consolidate all features into a unique set or we could leave duplicates in the system. Doing the second seems to actually be faster, because most feature sets don't have intra-example collisions._

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this should be mentioned in the documentation, so I'll join the conversation on the official page.